# How do I use touch as input with InkCanvas?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp-xaml

Is there a way where I can enable InkCanvas to take finger input as ink strokes? I'd like to use my fingertips to handwrite on the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

By default, ink is supported for pen input only. If you try to write or draw with your finger, you need to use InkPresenter object, which provides finer-grained management of the input, processing, and rendering of ink input (standard and modified) on your InkCanvas. About more details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/ink-walkthrough#introduction). And you can try the following code:

.xaml:

```
<InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" />
```

.cs:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    inkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;
}
```